# SQL query - how to aggregate only contiguous periods without lag or lead?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, self-join

I'am still a novice and excuse for my english. You see that I have two persons with different periods of time and I want to aggregate the periods if they are contiguous. I don't know how to use for example the `min()` and `max()` functions related to the next line or the line before to compare the date. Or is there in easier way to solve this? I only have SQL Server 2008 R2 without the lag and lead-functions.

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE( 
    PersonID INT, 
    FROM    date, 
    TO date 
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1,'2011-01-01','2011-04-30'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1,'2011-05-01','2011-08-31'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1,'2011-09-01','2011-12-31'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1,'2012-01-01','2012-03-31'

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2,'2011-03-01','2011-06-30'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2,'2011-07-01','2011-10-31'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2,'2013-01-01','2013-04-30'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2,'2013-05-01','2013-08-31'
```

I expect something like this and look especially on PersonID 2:

```
 PersonID FROM TO 
 1 , 2011-01-01 , 2012-03-31
 2 , 2011-03-01 , 2011-10-31
 2 , 2013-01-01 , 2013-08-31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard problem that would be made easier with cumulative sums and `lag()` or `lead()`.  You can still do the work.  I prefer to express it using correlated subqueries.

The logic starts by identifying which records are connected to the "next" record by an overlap.  The following query uses this logic to define `OverlapWithPrev`.

```
      select *
      from (select t.*,
                   (select top 1 1
                    from t t2
                    where t2.personid = t.personid and
                          t2.fromd < t.fromd and
                          t2.tod >= dateadd(d, -1, t.fromd)
                    order by t2.fromd
                   ) as OverlapWithPrev
            from t
           ) t
```

This takes on the value of `1` when there is a previous record and `NULL` when there is not one.

Then with this information, the query then finds for each record the *next* record that is not overlapped with the previous one (and on the same person).  When you have a sequence of overlapping records, then all will have the same such next record, and the next record is used for aggregation.

Here is the full query:

```
with tp as 
     (select *
      from (select t.*,
                   (select top 1 1
                    from t t2
                    where t2.personid = t.personid and
                          t2.fromd < t.fromd and
                          t2.tod >= dateadd(d, -1, t.fromd)
                    order by t2.fromd
                   ) as OverlapWithPrev
            from t
           ) t
     )
select personid, min(fromd) as fromd, max(tod) as tod
from (select tp.*,
             (select top 1 fromd
              from tp tp2
              where tp2.OverlapWithPrev is null and
                    tp2.personid = tp.personid and
                    tp2.fromd > tp.fromd
             ) as NextFromD
      from tp
     ) tp
group by personid, NextFromD;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b979c/9) is a SQLFiddle to show how it works.